# What's with the Rep Calc. on SO?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, daily-reputation-limit

I know the limit is 200 per day, but the behavior I saw yesterday was that I hit the limit and then some - fine.

Today when I view my stuff via the today & yesterday buttons, I see the amount is 185?! I know it was actually around 250 ignoring the limit. If that's true, I'm out 15 points because my rep hasn't changed based on what the totals are apparently for yesterday.

**Question**: Will I get that rep?  Or will the calculation be fixed for the yesterday link?

**Suggestion/Speculation**: I wonder if the rep calculation limit & other related limits (closing questions/etc) would be better served with a rolling 24 hour period instead.  It'd be more accurate, and allow more moderation ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically someone unaccepted an answer after you hit the limit, and you then didn't get any more votes. It happens. A rep recalc *may* give you the 15 points back, I'm not sure. (Sometimes recalcs do what I expect, other times they don't.) Try not to get too hung up about the odd bit of rep lost here and there. If you're hitting the cap regularly, you'll get to 10,000 sooner or later after which point it makes no pragmatic difference.

As for your speculation: that would make a complicated system even more complicated. My feelings about time-based rep caps are well-known though :)

Comment: Even if you don't regularly hit the cap it won't make much difference. I barely ask/answer questions on SO anywhere and I'm in the 7,000s ... Indeed, I'm not sure the 10K tools -- which I have access to in one of the SE sites where I'm a mod -- provide that much pragmatic benefit over close/reopen votes for the average user. Of course, I agree with the nut of your answer: Don't sweat your rep. :)

Comment: Yeah, there was an answer attributed to today that was for yesterday so that's the most likely situation.