# Hit reputation limit at 179?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“Recent activity” vote counts are missing/corrupt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/recent-activity-vote-counts-are-missing-corrupt)
>   [What’s with the Rep Calc. on SO?!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29492/whats-with-the-rep-calc-on-so)

I had a strange problem, I appeared to have hit the rep limit at 179 rather than 200? 
The thing to note in the image is the top question, the rep gained from the top question compared to the up votes and the rep gained today.

[image: a shot of rep]

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910630/in-php-how-in-an-array-itteration-do-i-add-entries-to-a-second-array-only-if-the/1910640#1910640) that I cannot gain upvotes on doesn't seem to be cw

Comment: Was one of your answers/questions moved to another site?

Comment: I haven't had any rep gains or added answers/questions on any of the other sites

Comment: I was going to suggest that maybe you'd cast 21 downvotes today - unlikely, but possible - but apparently you've only cast 4 total, so that's out.

Comment: This looks like the same issue as described at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29492/whats-with-the-rep-calc-on-so (no, not the link I provided in close-as-dupe: that was a mistake and I can't undo it)

Comment: ++ for the pictures. :D

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of interesting. You don't appear to have won any bounties (which don't always show up correctly on your "recent activity" page), and you don't seem to have gotten enough downvotes to remove the rep after reaching the cap. You appear to have clicked "Today" correctly, and I independently added up and verified the 179 total.

I'm stumped. (And before everyone bum rushes that answer and tests upvoting it, I already did, and his rep did not increase.)

Best answer, Yacoby, is to take solace in the fact that it is almost tomorrow. As I write this, I believe we are 1.5 hours or so away from the UTC date switching over.

Comment: maybe a reverted accepted answer of some kind?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable answer.

Comment: I have a feeling that it is due to an answer with 2 upvotes I deleted, which I assume would explain it.

Comment: These things can almost always be explained by deletions.

Comment: I now feel rather stupid, although I didn't realize that downvoting cost my maximum rep gained. I should have read the FAQ more carefully I suppose.

Comment: A diamond-moderator should probably perform a rep recalc for the guy and see if that helps...

Comment: @Æther: Bad girl! How could you be that nasty? :]